# List two Objective-C dot operators in an NSLog statement?

Tags: objective-c, class, object

If I want to print two values using an Objective-C dot operator with the NSLog statement, I would do it like so:

```
NSLog(@"The height is %i and the width is %i", myRect.height, myRect.width);
```

But is there any way in which I can list the height and width only metioning myRect once? After all, they're from the the same object and class. Is there some sort of shorthand like so?

```
NSLog(@"The height is %i and the width is %i", myRect.height, width);
```

PS. I know that the above code doesn't work, but am I missing something that would work similar to the code above?

Comment: No, there's no shorthand like this.

Comment: I do not think any OO language that would allow this and rightly so . Do not tell me you can do this in Python :)

Comment: What’s the type of `myRect`? Your own custom type or a Cocoa type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no shorthand.

Unspoken convention when accessing many fields from one object could be using really short names for the local variable of the object, so you only get eg `r.width, r.height`.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own helper routine:

```
void ReportDimensions(rectangle_t myRect) {
    NSLog(@"The height is %i and the width is %i", myRect.height, myRect.width);
    return;
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like this:

```
rectangle_t r = /* rectangle from somewhere */
ReportDimensions(r);
```

This saves you from re-typing the string and object name over and over again. You could even add this as a method of a `rectangle` class if you wanted to write this instead:

```
r.ReportDimensions();
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I have never used or written a helper Routine before. I'll have to look into that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myRect` is of type `CGSize` (since that's the only built-in type that has immediate `height` and `width` members), then **YES** there is:

```
NSLog(@"myRect: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(myRect));
```

There's also `NSStringFromCGSize`, `NSStringFromCGPoint`, etc.  These are built-in functions that do the member extraction for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I wanted accomplished.